# Does Postgres use index on BIGINT columns?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to understand whether Postgres uses indexes on BIGINT columns. The ddl to create the table and the corresponding index works. But when searching via Google, there were some articles (quite old) that said that there are some issues with BIGINT column indexes (they're not used). Unfortunately, I don't have enough sample data available to verify this using EXPLAIN.

```
create table ab.sample
(
  id integer primary key generated always as identity,
  some_id bigint
);

create unique index sample_some_id_idx on ab.sample(some_id);
```

Comment: There is no bias against indexes on `bigint` columns. You might share the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for a more detailed analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say under the right conditions (namely sufficient selectivity warranting an index scan), definitely...  what version are you on?

```
insert into sample (some_id)
select generate_series(1,1000000);

analyze sample;

explain
select *
from sample
where some_id between 500000 and 500010;
```

Results:

```
Index Scan using sample_some_id_idx on sample  (cost=0.42..2.84 rows=11 width=12)
  Index Cond: ((some_id >= 500000) AND (some_id <= 500010))
```